# vim highlight remove overwrite others hi

Tags: vim, highlight

I my [~/.vimrc](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) I use this syn for long lines

```
augroup longLines                                                                                   
     au!
     au! filetype zsh,sh,python,vim,c,cpp
         \ syn match ColorColumn /\%>80v.\+/ containedin=ALL
 augroup END
```

but this overwrite other syn, with

[image: ss]

without

[image: ss]

Why the `syn`overwrite other highlight?
this is notorious in the last lines

```
 sys.exit(1)
 import settings
```

have different colors, with syn, the lines lost normal highlight

Comment: Uhmm, okey .... Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: In `vim7.3` I use `:set cc=80`

Comment: @kev I don't like `cc` is very ugly, always show the column 80, my syn only is showed when the line have more of 80 chars

Comment: @ldigas the question is, why the `syn` overwrite other hi ?

Comment: You can highlight with `underline`

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code:

```
highlight TooLongLine term=reverse ctermfg=Yellow ctermbg=Red
autocmd BufEnter,WinEnter * if &tw && !exists('b:DO_NOT_2MATCH') |
            \                 execute '2match TooLongLine /\S\%>'.(&tw+1).'v/' |
            \               endif
autocmd BufLeave,WinLeave * 2match

command -nargs=0 -bar Dm let b:DO_NOT_2MATCH=1 | 2match
command -nargs=0 -bar Sm execute '2match TooLongLine /\S\%>'.(&tw+1).'v/' |
            \            silent! unlet b:DO_NOT_2MATCH
```

If you don’t want to be able to remove this highlighting, depend on textwidth and insist on highlighting spaces that go beyond the limit, then you can truncate this to just

```
2match TooLongLine /.\%>80v/
```

This solution uses `match-highlight` that does not scrap syntax highlighting, but always overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you asked this quite some time ago, but in case if other people ask too, perhaps you could try using the `matchadd()` function, instead, like this:

```
hi def longLine gui=reverse    "or guibg=pink, or whatever you prefer
augroup longLines
    au!
    au! filetype zsh,sh,python,vim,c,cpp
                \ call matchadd("longLine", "\\%>80v", 0, 9999)
augroup END
```

Most importantly, make sure that you do NOT set the `guifg` of whatever highlight group you decide to use.  That would overwrite your syntax highlighting.

Another important part (for me, at least) is to use `matchadd` with `0` as the third parameter so that your Search highlighting remains effective and doesn't get overtaken by the longLine highlighting.

The fourth parameter can be omitted.  It's just a constant so that you can `:call matchdelete(9999)` to easily remove the highlighting again later, if you want.

See `:h matchadd` and `:h matchdelete`